# How can I disable Object control on mouse click?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It's x-axis object when user move the mouse pointer and then click. Object falls on the ground at the same mouse pointer position. But when object is falling if user move the position of pointer it also affect the object falling position. I only want object falls on that position where user click and does not control the object when falling on the ground.
Code:

```
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {

    Rigidbody2D body;
    float mousePosInBlocks;

    void Start () {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        body.isKinematic = true;

    }

    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {

            body.isKinematic = false;
        }

        Vector3 ballPos = new Vector3 (0f, this.transform.position.y, 0f);
        mousePosInBlocks = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x;


        //not go outside from border
        ballPos.x = Mathf.Clamp (mousePosInBlocks, -2.40f, 2.40f);

        body.position = ballPos;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a simple `bool` to your script like `bool hasClicked` which you set to `true` after the user clicks the left mouse button. If `hasClicked == true`, don't change the `body.position` anymore. Alternatively, rely on the `isKinematic` property of the `Rigidbody`, which you alread set to `true` after a leftclick.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt can you write this code with above script in your Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folloup from my comment. Just exit out of the function after the mouse click appeared. There really isn't more to it than that.

```cs
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {

    Rigidbody2D body;
    float mousePosInBlocks;
    bool wasDropped = false;

    void Start () {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        body.isKinematic = true;
    }

    void Update () {
        //Don't do anything after the ball is dropped.
        if(wasDropped)
            return;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            body.isKinematic = false;
            wasDropped = true;
        }

        Vector3 ballPos = new Vector3 (0f, this.transform.position.y, 0f);
        mousePosInBlocks = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x;
        //not go outside from border
        ballPos.x = Mathf.Clamp (mousePosInBlocks, -2.40f, 2.40f);

        body.position = ballPos;
    }
}
```

Comment: if(wasDropped)
            return; what this is doing

Comment: Exit out of the function (`Update()` in this case) if the ball was dropped, which is set on the left mouse button. It prevents the execution of all the code under it, which changes the position of the ball.